# How to install Podman, rootless container in Mac OSX.Brew?

Tags: homebrew, podman

I'm looking for an easy way to install Podman in osx.

Are there some brew commands to install Podman?

Answer (score 8):

From the installation information I can see the osx installations is supported via [homebrew](https://github.com/containers/libpod/blob/master/install.md).

**MacOS
Using Homebrew:
brew cask install podman**

Answer (score 4):

*Update:* Use `brew install podman` as described [here](https://podman.io/getting-started/installation.html).

There won't be any Mac or Windows support (at least not in the near future). Instead, you would have to run podman on a linux-based system and connect to it using [varlink](https://varlink.org/). For details, see [this blog article](https://podman.io/blogs/2019/01/16/podman-varlink.html).